# How to stop component re-render in react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a component that will receive the notification from firebase.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import NotificationScreen from '../../Components/Notification/Notification';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { getCache } from '../../Services/CachingService';

const Notification = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [notificationList, setNotificationList] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    getCache('messages').then((messages) => {
      console.log(`messages`, messages);
      if (messages) {
        setNotificationList(messages);
      }
    });
  }, [notificationList]);

  return (
    <NotificationScreen
      NotificationDetails={notificationList}
      onSendNotificationPress={() => navigation.navigate('NotificationMembers')}
    />
  );
};

export default Notification;
```

When the component gets a new notification from firebase it should re-render. Now that component is re-rendering but has not stopped continuously re-rendering.

How to stop?

Comment: You are updating the state inside the `useEffect` hook that is also unnecessarily added in the dependency array. Fix: `}, [notificationList])` ----> `}, [setNotificationList]`

Comment: You will also probably need to merge old state with the new one which can be done as: `setNotificationList(currentNotificationList => [...currentNotificationList, ...messages])`.

Comment: cache had all previous messages

Comment: Hello I hope you are doing well, I guess that the problem comes from getCache function, Please could you update your question with that function. Thank you. @AsZik

Answer (score 0):

The solution is you need to use React Memo.

Class components can bail out from rendering when their input props are the same using PureComponent or shouldComponentUpdate. Now you can do the same with function components by wrapping them in React memo.

Example:

```
const MyComponent = React.memo(function MyComponent(props) {
  /* only rerenders if props change */
});
```

Please refer to this article

https://linguinecode.com/post/prevent-re-renders-react-functional-components-react-memo

@Yousaf

Following is the code and code pen attached. You can observe the no of renderings

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const d = React.memo((value) => {
  const ref = useRef();

  const isEqual = ref.current && ref.current.join(',') === value.join(',');
  console.log(ref.current, value);
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  });
  if (isEqual) {
    return "notchanged";
  }
  return value;
});

const Notification = () => {
  const [notifications, setNotifications] = useState([]);

  const changed = d.type(notifications);
  var s = 1;

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Rendering....");
    setInterval(() => {
      setNotifications([11]);
   
    }, 1000);
  }, [changed]);

  return <div>Test {notifications}</div>;
};

export default Notification;
```

[Codepen Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-cache-ef8sm?file=/src/Notification.js)

Comment: whoever downvoted your answer most likely did so because your answer is incorrect. [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69281265/how-to-stop-component-re-render-in-react-hooks#comment122452772_69281265) explains the cause of infinite re-rendering. `React.memo` won't solve OP's problem of infinite re-rendering.

Comment: Why not create a codesandbox demo in which you reproduce this problem by updating component's state inside the `useEffect` hook and also add that state in the dependency array of the `useEffect` hook. This will cause the infinite re-rendering problem. Then try to solve the problem using `React.memo()`. If you are able to solve it, plz share the link. I would be happy to learn more about react.

Comment: 1. How do you know that i was the one who downvoted your answer? Seems like you are the one making a judgement here. 2. I would be happy to upvote your answer if you can create a demo in which you solve this problem with `React.memo`.

Comment: @Yousaf, I attached the React. memo. If you won't use memorize function it loops infinite

Comment: 1. Demo you created doesn't produces reproduces the problem of infinite re-rendering in the first place, so `React.memo` isn't fixing anything in your code. 2. Even without `React.memo`, you will get the same number of re-renders, so `React.memo` is actually unnecessary in your case. 3. You made your demo too complicated to fix the problem that wasn't there in the first place. 4. OP's problem can simply be solved by just removing `notificationList` from the dependency array of the `useEffect` hook.

Comment: @Yousaf, nope, it will be solved by simply creating a single value instead of an array. But it is always we need to use memo either we can use as a component or we can use as function. useEffect(() => {}, [1,22,33]) will always treated as new object. It doesn't do a deep copy. I explained with setInterval, give directly notifications of changed you will observed re renders